# How to animate a ProgressBar Value Property using Storyboard DoubleAnimation in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a Windows 8.1 application with a Progress defined as follows

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="myProgressBar" Opacity="1" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="0"/>
```

I have the following StoryBoard animation defined as follows.

```
<Storyboard x:Name="myStoryBoard">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myProgressBar"
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value"
                     From="0"
                     To="100"
                     Duration="00:00:04" />
</Storyboard>
```

This C# code behind calls the begin function of the Storyboard.

```
myStoryBoard.Begin();
```

But I don't see any change in the Value Property of the ProgressBar.

However if I apply a similar StoryBoard animation for Opacity property of the same ProgressBar, it works seamlessly, I can see the ProgressBar fading away as expected.

```
<Storyboard x:Name="myOpacityStoryBoard">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myProgressBar"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                         From="1"
                         To="0"
                         Duration="0:0:4">
</Storyboard>
```

I am not sure what's happening. I checked that the Value Property is a double just like how Opacity is. Am I doing something wrong?

I would be glad if someone can guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add `EnableDependentAnimation="True"` to your animation.

```
<Storyboard x:Name="myStoryBoard">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myProgressBar"
             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value"
             EnableDependentAnimation="True"
             From="0"
             To="100"
             Duration="00:00:04" />
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: Thanks. Why was this additional property "EnableDependentAnimation" not required with Opacity?

Comment: Because opacity is an independent animation. For more information see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj819807#dependent